# Map's entries to separate columns in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, jpa-2.0

Suppose I have a `Players` table:

```
ID | name  | email | age | ...
1  | 'bob' | null  | 23  | ...
```

There is a lot of columns (say, 50) and each (apart from `ID`) might be null. Please disregard the table design, it's has to stay this way for now :-(

I'd want to map this table to an entity (i.e. i'd like it to work for both saving and reading):

```
public class Player implements Serializable {  
    private Map<String, String> attributes;
    // more code, ctor, setters, getters etc...
}
```

where each column in the table is read as an entry to the map. So in the given example the map would have keys `ID`, `name`, `email` etc. with appropriate values.

I can live with a separate `id` member if that's required by Hibernate, but **I want to avoid having 50 members in one class**.

Is this possible in Hibernate 4?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if maintaining a `Map` is possible and if it is, how does it impact readability.

But you can use the `@Embeddable` and `@AttributeOverride` anotations instead.

In order to avoid having 50 members in one class, you can group the members by some common property and place each of the groups in a separate class. Then, you will have to annotate each of the classes with `@Embeddable` which will make their instance Embeddable objects (or components). These are objects whose properties are mapped to the same table as the owning entity's table. For example, let's say you've decided to group the `name`, `age` and `email` properties in a single class, called `PersonalData`

Optionally, you can name the properties whatever you like, but then you will have to use the `@Column` annotation to tell Hibernate about which exact database table-column are you talking about.

```
@Embeddable
public class PersonalData implements Serializable {
    private String fullname;

    private String email;

    private String age;

    //accessors
}
```

You can create as much as `@Embeddable`-annotatated classes you need. It's not a good idea to have a single `@Embeddable` class with 50 members, so you can spread the members across several classes.

After done, we go back to the `@Entity`-annotated class. Its members will be instances of the `@Embeddable` classes annotated with the `Embeddable` anotation. The `@AttributeOverrides` annotation will be helpful to match each of the embedded component's members to a specific database table-column. For example:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Embedded (
        @AttributeOverrides(name = "fullname", column = @Column(name = "name"))
        @AttributeOverrides(name = "email", column = @Column(name = "email"))
        @AttributeOverrides(name = "age", column = @Column(name = "age"))
    )
    private PersonalData personalData;

    //other @Embedded-annotated members.
}
```

Comment: I like the `@Embeddable` idea, I thought about it.. unfortunately, the columns are quite unrelated and it would be an artificial "grouping"

Comment: Well ... it's not that a huge blocker. Try it out. :)