# Retrieve a row from DB as a Map in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

Table `Players`:

```
ID | name  | email | age | ...
1  | 'bob' | null  | 23  | ...
```

This table is where instances of class `Player` are persisted (one row per instance, no composition etc.).

Having a Hibernate `Session`, **how do I get the row** (say with id - the PK - equal to 1) **as a Java Map** (key = column name, value = cell value) ?

Example usage:

```
Map<String,String> row = getPlayerByIdAsMap(1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a query with `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer`; is verbose but should works with Hibernate property definition and not with JavaBean definition (they can differ).

```
Map<String,Object> aliasToValueMap = 
    session.createCriteria(User.class)
      .add(Restrictions.idEq(userID))
      .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.id().as("id"))
        // Add others properties
      )
      .setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
    .uniqueResult();
```

A worse approch can be write a custom ResultTransformer that introspect ClassMetadata and try to extract values...

```
class IntrospectClassMetadata extends BasicTransformerAdapter {
  PassThroughResultTransformer rt = PassThroughResultTransformer.INSTANCE;
  public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
    final Object o = rt.transformTuple(tuple, aliases);
    ClassMetadata cm = sf.getClassMetadata(o.getClass());
    List<String> pns = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cm.getPropertyNames()));
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for(String pn : pns) {
      m.put(pn, cm.getPropertyValue(o, pn));
    }
    m.put(cm.getIdentifierPropertyName(), cm.getIdentifier(o));
    return m;
  }
}
```

and use

```
Map<String,Object> aliasToValueMap = 
        session.createCriteria(User.class)
          .add(Restrictions.idEq(userID))
          .setResultTransformer(new IntrospectClassMetadata())
        .uniqueResult();
```

Last chance:

```
Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>)s.createSQLQuery("select * from user where id = :id")
  .setParameter("id",p.id)
  .setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
.uniqueResult();
```

but this doesn't map list,bags and other mapped object, but only raw column names and values...

Comment: This would return a `Map`? Could you complete the example with a couple of keystrokes so it's cristal-clear how to use?

Comment: do you know if the opposite is possible, i.e. **save** a `Map` to a table? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904041/maps-entries-to-separate-columns-in-hibernate please

Comment: I'd love to accept your answer but the way it's right now it returns a `Map<String, Player>` rather than `List<Map<String,Object>>`.. and the key to that map is `this`, lol.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you you need to specify a projections :/ or a custom (but a not-so-safe custom ResultTransformer)

Comment: God, this is terrible. I have ca. 50 columns.. Why is this so **ridiculously complicated** to read a row as a map ...

Comment: I think is because it is an ORM and has facilities to map raw values to entity, not the opposite...
Last chance, check my edit...I have no more ideas :(

Comment: **yes**, the "last chance" does work! I don't think I need anything else **except** you have hardcoded the table name - is it possible to specify the table by giving a `Class`, like in other examples?

Comment: you can extract `@Table.name` value from annotatated Class parameter like Hibernate do

Answer (score 2):

You can use HQL and do a query for [selecting the result as a new Map](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)

```
select new Map(p.id as ID, p.name as name, p.email as email, p.age as age)
from Player p
```

It will return you a collection of maps, being each one of the maps a row in the query result.

Comment: Cool, can you tell Hibernate to map all columns or do you have to list them all? I mean, I have 50 columns..

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. You'll have to specify every element of the map.

Comment: So I think @bellabax solution will be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeanUtils and do something like this:

```
User user = (User) session.get(User.class, userID);
Map map = BeanUtils.describe(user);
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about it, but `describe` adds the `class` property and reports nested objects as .. objects (I use `@Embedded on them`) and not as a set of their properties.

Comment: Do you need exactly a Map?  I guess JSONObject can do some recursive transformation into a json format, then you can access it more or less like a Map of Maps

Comment: The other answers look more Hibernate-specific and quite more interesting though :P