# groovy hibernate createSQLQuery access to ResultSetMetaData?

Tags: sql, hibernate, groovy

I have a simple groovy/grails SQL query where I would like to access the MetaData from the query result, but I am not sure how.

Code sample:

```
String sqlString = “select * from my_table where id = :myID”
def queryParams = [ myID: 1 ]
final sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sqlString)
final queryResults = sqlQuery.with {
    setProperties( queryParams )
    list()
}

queryResults.collect { r ->
    r.each{ c ->
        // I extract result data here
    }
}
```

I see that

```
sqlQuery.class == org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl
queryResults.class == java.util.ArrayList
```

I saw the following article
Groovy Goodness: Access ResultSetMetaData with Groovy SQL:
(http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/09/groovy-goodness-access.html) but can I get to the ResultSetMetaData using the queryReults code above?

Edit 1: I think I could use AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer
([Retrieve a row from DB as a Map in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016152/retrieve-a-row-from-db-as-a-map-in-hibernate)) if I can figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you albciff, I also found another solution:
I read the post [Retrieve a row from DB as a Map in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016152/retrieve-a-row-from-db-as-a-map-in-hibernate), and discovered that I could use AliasToEntityMapResultsTransformer with the sqlQuery code as I had it:

```
final queryResults = sqlQuery.with {
    setProperties( queryParams )
    setResultsTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultsTransformer.INSTANCE)
    list()
}
```

then it would return a HashMap containing the column name in the results:

```
queryResults.collect { r ->
    r.each{ k, v ->
        // k = key from MetaData = table column, v = value
    }
}
```

I did notice that the order of the columns in the resutls no longer matched the order of the fields in the SQL query, but since it returned the column names now this did not matter.

Answer (score 1):

The [link](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/09/groovy-goodness-access.html)  you refers in the question gets the metadata using directly JDBC classes.

With hibernate in the way you're using it I think you cannot get the metadata. [`list()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/impl/SQLQueryImpl.html#list()) method on `org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl` returns a list of your result values, if each row has more than one result then it return a list of `object[]` however in this `object[]` you only have the values of the columns on your table but not the metadata like for example the column name.

To do this with hibernate; if you have your entities defined in a classes you can use the follow approach to get the metadata:

```
def metadataForMyEntity = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(YourEntities.class)
def columnNames = metadataForMyEntity .getPropertyNames()
def columnTypes = metadataForMyEntity.getPropertyTypes();
```

See [`SessionFactory`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getClassMetadata(java.lang.String)) and [`ClassMetadata`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html).

Instead if you want to avoid the creation of entities and you want to do in the same way that in the JDBC, use JDBC directly like in the article you refer:

```
import groovy.sql.*
def db = Sql.newInstance('yourConnectionString', 'user', 'password', 'driver')
String sqlString = 'select * from my_table where id = 1'
def rows = db.rows(sqlString , { meta ->
   ....
}
```

By the way note that in your example there is a typo, you define `queryResults` but then you're trying to use `queryReults` to iterate the results `:)`.

Hope this helps,