# Join array in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have 2 entities: A and B.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
class A{
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mapped by="a")
    private Set<B> b;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
class B{
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="a")
    private A a;
}
```

When i'm trying to make something like

```
Query q=sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("select a.id, bArray
 from A as a join a.b as bArray");
```

i'm getting not collection of B, but one B-object. How can i get A-class and collection of related with it B-objects? I.e. in debugger there is not Set with 1 element, there is just B-element.

Comment: `select distinct a from A a left join fetch a.b` will return the As, each with its loaded set of Bs. There's no way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Query q=sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("select a.id, bArray
 from A as a join a.b as bArray");
```

With above query, you will get only one object for B not a collection because basically the query is just performing the join between A and B and returning all the possible tuples ( select a , b from A as a inner join B as b)

You can set a custom result transformer for custom results processing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016152/retrieve-a-row-from-db-as-a-map-in-hibernate)

But anyway in your case, you can simply pre-fetch "b" objects along with "a" object by using join fetch as below query.

```
Query q=sessionFactory.openSession().createQuery("select a from A as a join fetch a.b ");
```